# C-Like Array in TCL

Tags: c, arrays, data-structures, tcl

I'm porting a program from C to TCL, and I'm trying to implement a data structure similar to an Array in C. The two main things I need it to do are

- Be Ordered
- Allow insertion into any index
- Return the array from a procedure

I will know the size of the array before run time, and the size should not change throughout the program (so it is static). Are there any data structures that fit this bill?

I'm using TCL 8.6 if that matters

EDIT: I also need to be able to return the data structure from a function.

Comment: The thing that matches a C array is a Tcl list. (They're implemented with C arrays behind the scenes.) You can return them as they're ordinary copy-on-write values, and they inherently know their order. Setting a value at an index — your second operation — is done with `lset` (or `lreplace` if used right). True _insertion_ makes the list longer and usually uses `linsert`. It's also not what you're apparently asking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The corresponding data structure would be `list`. It meets all your requirements. If you want it to have a fixed size, you "pre-allocate" it like this:

```
set data [lrepeat 8 {}]
```

which creates eight empty compartments.

It is ordered, you can access every element by index (0-based), and you can pass its value into procedures/functions and also return it. You can traverse it with e.g. `foreach` and `for`, and there are a lot of list manipulating commands.

---

While `list` is the Tcl data container that corresponds most closely to a C array, one can use `array` or `dict` to simulate a fixed-size, direct-access, ordered container.

```
# allocation
set listdata [lrepeat 8 {}]
array set arraydata {0 {} 1 {} 2 {} 3 {} 4 {} 5 {} 6 {} 7 {}}
set dictdata [dict create 0 {} 1 {} 2 {} 3 {} 4 {} 5 {} 6 {} 7 {}]
# or
set dictdata {0 {} 1 {} 2 {} 3 {} 4 {} 5 {} 6 {} 7 {}}

# access (write, then read)
lset listdata 5 96
lindex $listdata 5 ;# -> 96
set arraydata(5) 96
set arraydata(5) ;# -> 96
dict set dictdata 5 96
dict get $dictdata 5 ;# -> 96

# return from procedure
# (not possible with arraydata, arrays are shared using either
# scope manipulation or namespaces)
return $listdata
return $dictdata

# traversal
for {set i 0} {$i < 8} {incr i} {puts [lindex $listdata $i]}
# or
foreach elem $listdata {puts $elem}
for {set i 0} {$i < 8} {incr i} {puts [lindex $arraydata($i)]}
dict for {idx val} $dictdata {puts $val}
```

Documentation: [array](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/array.htm), [dict](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/dict.htm), [for](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/for.htm), [foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm), [incr](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/incr.htm), [lindex](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lindex.htm), [lrepeat](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lrepeat.htm), [lset](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lset.htm), [puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm), [return](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/return.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm)

Comment: If it's preallocated, it will allow me to insert objects where ever I want, correct?

Comment: @Sawyer: yes, it will.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. You even added examples after I already accepted your answer. I cannot thank you enough.

Comment: @Sawyer: no problem. Good luck with the porting.

Answer (score 1):

Either the tcl [array](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/array.htm) ([some examples](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/Tcl22.html)) or the tcl [dict](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/dict.htm) command will suit your needs.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "a new ordering". Basically, I want a box with 8 compartments. Compartments are labeled 0 through 7. I can put something in compartment 7, even if compartments 0 thru 6 are empty. If I iterate through what's in my box, it will go "Compartment0, Compartment1, ... Compartment7" every time. Hopefully this makes sense.